# how constructor could be called sooner than member variables in a class?

Tags: c++

consider following code:
I know that when you create an object of class C first member variables will be constructed then order of construction will be ***abc***   and deconstruction ***CBA*** . now question is that if there is a way to call constructor of class C sooner than member variables ?  to have order of ***cab*** and for deconstruction ***BAC***

how i could change order  that way first constructor of class be called then member variables.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <exception>

class A {
public:
  A() {
    std::cout << 'a';

  }
  ~A() { std::cout << 'A'; }
};


class B {
public:
  B() { std::cout << 'b'; }
  ~B() { std::cout << 'B'; }

};

class C {
public:
  C() {
    std::cout << 'c';

  }
  ~C() { std::cout << 'C'; }

    A m_a ;
    B m_b;
        };


void foo() {  C c; }

int main() {
  try {
    foo();
  }
  catch (std::exception &) {
    std::cout << "catch";

  }
}
```

Comment: The answer is "no", you can't get the constructor body to be called before the member initializers. But there may still be a solution to your original problem -- what would you do inside that "early construction", and what does it need access to ?

Comment: You can't. You *could* make the members dynamic smart pointers and create+initialize them inside the body of `C::C()` (which isn't really advisable). Beyond that you're options are pretty-much non-existent in the given code. I'm sure you have a reason for trying to sidestep a feature of the language itself (an object cannot begin functional construction until it's members are fully constructed), but this has the strong aroma of an [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More of a workaround than actually breaking construction order (which isn't possible). Store the members by smart pointer.

```
class C {
public:
  C() {
    std::cout << 'c';
    m_a = std::make_unique<A>();
    m_b = std::make_unique<B>();
  }
  ~C() { 
     m_b.reset();
     m_a.reset();
     std::cout << 'C';
   }

    std::unique_ptr<A> m_a;
    std::unique_ptr<B> m_b;
};
```

The instances of the actual objects you care about can now be created at the end of `C`'s constructor. Of course, you pay for it by doing dynamic memory allocation.

Another solution can be to use aligned storage and placement new construction:

```
class C {
public:
  C() {
    std::cout << 'c';
    new(&m_a) A;
    new(&m_B) B;
  }
  ~C() { 
     m_b.~B();
     m_a.~A();
     std::cout << 'C';
   }

    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(A), alignof(A)>::type m_a;
    std::aligned_storage<sizeof(B), alignof(B)>::type m_b;
};
```

But either way you have to be **very** careful and follow to [rule of three/five](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/rule_of_three).

Comment: I suggest adding `m_a.reset(); m_b.reset();` inside the destructor to also achieve the desired output.

Answer (score 1):

Or simply:

```
class C {
public:
    A *m_a;
    B *m_b;

      C() {
        std::cout << 'c';
        m_a = new A;
        m_b = new B;
      }
    ~C() {
        delete m_b;
        delete m_a;
        std::cout << 'C'; }
        };
```

Use smart pointers to ensure exception safeness